# Different p value of two different function in R while computing Cramér-von Mises test

Tags: r, p-value

When I tried to run Cramér-von Mises for generalized extreme value distribution in R, I got different p value for cvm.test function and gnfit function. The difference is quite significant like 0.07. Which one should I use?

Comment: Since any package may use any function name, please identify the packages you're calling the functions from. I expect one is accounting for parameter estimation while the other is for a fully specified distribution, but it's not possible to tell for sure with the information given. Or maybe you didn't specify parameters at all for one of them in which case the p-value would probably be nonsense

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used gnFit package for gnfit and goftest package for the cvm.test, I have already input the same parameter for both tests. For gnfit, the cramer-von misses stats 0.024 with pval 0.92312 and cvm. test' cvm stat 0.024767 with pval 0.9904

Comment: The difference in those two p-values is not 0.7. Please edit any additional information into your question, rather than putting it in comments. Oh; also note that it's *Cramér-von Mises* (i.e. one s in the middle of Mises).

Comment: Sorry my bad, thanks for the information anyway

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the difference relates to what I suggested in the first sentence of my first comment.

Looking at the help for each function, the difference between the statistics would appear to be explained by the fact that it looks like `gnFit::gnfit` is computing an adjusted statistic as per Chen and Balakrishnan -- for a distribution with parameters estimated by maximum likelihood -- while `goftest::cvm.test`  looks to be for a fully specified distribution - i.e. where you specify the parameters before you see the data.

(Even if both were doing parameter estimation they appear to be relying on different papers which could well produce different approximations)

The functions /"tables" that convert test statistics to p-values are also likely to be different.